# IE9 Compatibility View

Tags: php, wordpress, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I don't have IE9 to mess around with this, so it's a general question.

I built a site for a client WordPress (latest version)
Performs fine on all browsers 'including' IE9

The clients 'tech' expert has switched their browsers on the network to Compatibility view ON by Default.

On Their PC's there is one gallery (timthumb.php) where the images don't load (sticks on loading graphic). All other galleries are fine even though they are the same code

I had a friend test on IE9 Comp ON and all was fine.

Question - should Compatibility view be on by Default - does it install OFF or ON?
Client thinks now that people generally will have problems viewing the site.

I was under the impression that it should be OFF unless a site doesn't display properly.

Any advice would be great.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compatibility view is OFF by default, but there are enough older versions < 8 of IE around that you should consider creating your sites so that they at least offer an alternative for those.

However, if it's just the client who has to be satisfied, you can try to force IE into standard mode by adding the following to the html head:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Note that Microsoft doesn't encourage to use this mode in production. You can read about that [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/cc817574.aspx).

If you are really developing websites, you *need* IE9 (for testing) along with all other important browsers. Consider using [IE Tester](http://my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage) which lets you render your pages in all IE versions since 5.5.

Comment: Thanks Olaf, that's constructive. It is only compatibility view that causes this one error. I know that the office is on a small Microsoft Exchange Network so I assume that the browsers have all been set to compat on...I assume that should really be set to off?

Comment: Well, they may have a reason to set compat mode to on - maybe an old intranet site they are using needs it, or the sysadmins think the new mode is evil. There is no general 'should' or 'should not', but I'd say they 'should not' do it without reason.

Comment: Thanks - last question, does it make sense that a site working in IE9 should have a problem with C View on do you think?

Comment: 'Make sense' may not be the correct term, but it happens a lot that pages don't work in quirks mode. It's a necessary consideration whether to satisfy both modes, and there are definitely quite a few modules out there that simply don't work in compat mode.

Answer (score 0):

Compatibility view is off by default... it is optional.